# ASN1C compiling

Tags: c++, c, encoding, asn.1

I have a small asn1 code:

---------------------ASN1 FILE------------------------------

```
RectangleModule1 DEFINITIONS ::= 
BEGIN
Rectangle ::= SEQUENCE (SIZE(1..10)) OF SEQUENCE {

 item CHOICE    {

  height INTEGER,

  width  IA5String

 } --# UNTAGGED
}

END
```

When I compile it with asn1c, it gives me the Rectangle.c and Rectangle.h files. The output of Rectangle looks like this:

-----------------------Rectangle.h------------------------------

```
/* Dependencies */

typedef enum item_PR {
  item_PR_NOTHING,    /* No components present */
item_PR_height,
item_PR_width
  } item_PR;

/* Rectangle */
typedef struct Rectangle {
  A_SEQUENCE_OF(struct Member {
    struct item {
        item_PR present;
        union item_u {
            long     height;
            IA5String_t  width;
        } choice;

        /* Context for parsing across buffer boundaries */
        asn_struct_ctx_t _asn_ctx;
    } item;

    /* Context for parsing across buffer boundaries */
    asn_struct_ctx_t _asn_ctx;
  } ) list;

  /* Context for parsing across buffer boundaries */
  asn_struct_ctx_t _asn_ctx;
 } Rectangle_t;
```

but I wanted my output to look like this:

```
  /* Dependencies */
  typedef enum item_PR_sl {
  item_PR_NOTHING_sl,    /* No components present */
  item_PR_height_sl,
  item_PR_width_sl
  } item_PR_sl;

  /* Rectangle */
  typedef struct Rectangle {
  A_SEQUENCE_OF(struct Member {
        struct item_sl {
        item_PR_sl present;
        union item_u_sl {
            long     height;
            IA5String_t  width;
        } choice;

        /* Context for parsing across buffer boundaries */
        asn_struct_ctx_t _asn_ctx;
    } item;

    /* Context for parsing across buffer boundaries */
    asn_struct_ctx_t _asn_ctx;
} ) list;

/* Context for parsing across buffer boundaries */
asn_struct_ctx_t _asn_ctx;
  } Rectangle_t;
```

---

i.e., _sl to be concatenated to item fields. I was unable to do this by changing the asn file. I don't know how the `constr_CHOICE` and `constr_SEQUENCE` are working. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What asn1c do you use?

Comment: Why is it important for the generated code to have specific names?

Comment: @Errandir: ASN.1 Compiler, v0.9.24.
Copyright (c) 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006 Lev Walkin <vlm@lionet.info>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After spending few hours of time, I figured that it can't be done by modifying the **asn** file. It can only be done by editing the **.h** and **.c** files generated by compiling asn file.